# iOS/Unity3D/Pushwoosh: Provisioning profile no APS entry

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, provisioning, pushwoosh

I'm having a lot of trouble with integrating pushwoosh, a service that lets one send push messages via web to a phone, in my iOS distribution app that I have created in Unity 3D.
A few weeks ago, during test development, I integrated the service without any problems. In the certificates section of the developer portal from Apple, I had a beta App ID that allowed push notifications; I had my app peacefully running on my phone. The provisioning profile I used for that was a Development profile.

However now I want to port my app to distribution. I created a new App ID since the other I mentioned was associated with testing/beta. I also created two new provisioning profiles, both associated with this App ID: one for Ad Hoc Distribution and one for App Store distribution. Then I changed the app ID my project was associated with to this new one and I added an APN Production Certificate to the Ad Hoc profile so that push notifications were allowed.
I also did check and redo everything the documentation of pushwoosh provided, but every time I build my project, it starts running on my phone with the message:

```
Pushwoosh Error
Your provisioning profile does not have APS entry. Please make sure your profile is push compatible.
```

I have checked the provisioning profiles on my phone. I have the Ad Hoc profile, I checked it on my Mac and in the xml `aps-environment` value is set to `production` (and not `development`, so this setting should not be the problem). But what IS going on? Starting to get desperate; my folders are full of csr, cer and p12 files with all resembling names at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. It turns out "Ad Hoc testing" was quite different from what I thought it was...
[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) about Beta/Ad Hoc Testing helped me out here. If you follow this guide and have added the right certificates in iTunes connect, you should be fine.